# How to computer CRC32/MD5 of a specific file withing my APK

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the CRC or MD5 of a specific file  (Activity) in my Application (within my APK) so that  I can compare that value in another file and make sure that the first file has not been tampered with.

Can I do that? Is so, can you guide me with it?

Example:

Let say I have file A.java and B.java.  I want to calculate A.java CRC32/MD5 and store this value in B.java so that when B.java executes it recalaculates A.java and compares it to the known value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. There are no separate class files on Android, you get a single DEX file with all classes and libraries compiled in. You have to compute the hash of the classes.dex file and store it in a resource file, because putting it in a class file will change the overall hash value. However, if I decompile your app and changes your classes.dex, I can also changes the resources, so that doesn't really offer any real protection. Of course, you can try to obfuscate or hide the value to make it harder, but some tools will look for CRC/MessageDigest references and simply hook them to return the same value every time.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, how can I compute the hash value of DEX file? As long as it is manual work for the hacker, I am good. I just don't want a tool like luckypatcher cracking my app

Comment: You can use `Context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir` to find where the APK is and lokk for the classes.dex inside (hint: an APK is a zip file). Then just use `MessageDigest` to calculate the hash. Of course, things like Lucky Patcher modify the dalvik cache directly, so you won't detect this using this approach. To get around this you can do tricks like manually loading and optimizing stuff with DexFile, computing the hash and comparing with what's in the actual cache, but it is generally not worth it unless you are going after a particular tool/exploit.

Comment: Accepted. Thats exacty what I am trying to do. I want to get around lucky patcher specifically. So you are saying this Hash calculate wont help in this? Do you have a link to a tutorial or pointer to how do manual loading/optimizing or the dealing with cache. I feel you got me closer and I just need hint pleaaaaase:)

Comment: This one is in Russian, but is has code and with Google Translate you should get the idea: http://goandroid.net/2012/06/09/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-dalvik-cache-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0/

Answer (score 1):

Get the contents of A.java into a string using a [java.io.BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and proceed as follows:

```
public byte[] getMD5(String fileAContents) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
     MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     messageDigest.update(fileAContents.getBytes());
     return messageDigest.digest();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but when my code execute while packaged in apk file, what would b the path of the file? And should it be. Java or. Class. I need it computed during runtime

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void calculate(Context context) {

    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        ZipInputStream fis = get(context);
        System.out.println("fis: " + fis);

        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

        int nread = 0; 
        while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
          md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
        };
        byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
          sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<mdbytes.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & mdbytes[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + hexString.toString());

        if(fis!=null){
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ZipInputStream get(Context context){

      // Get the path to the apk container.
    String apkPath = context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir;
    JarFile containerJar = null;

    try {

        // Open the apk container as a jar..
        containerJar = new JarFile(apkPath);

        // Look for the "classes.dex" entry inside the container.
        ZipEntry zzz = containerJar.getEntry("classes.dex");

        // If this entry is present in the jar container 
        if (zzz != null) {

            System.out.println("long " + zzz.getCrc());

             // Get an Input Stream for the "classes.dex" entry
            InputStream in = containerJar.getInputStream(zzz);

             ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);

             return zin;
        }   

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (containerJar != null)
            try {
                containerJar.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    return null;
}
```